# What's the best way to "smudge" an image programmatically?

Tags: image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm messing around with image manipulation, mostly using Python.  I'm not too worried about performance right now, as I'm just doing this for fun.  Thus far, I can load bitmaps, merge them (according to some function), and do some REALLY crude analysis (find the brightest/darkest points, that kind of thing).

I'd like to be able to take an image, generate a set of control points (which I can more or less do now), and then smudge the image, starting at a control point and moving in a particular direction.  What I'm not sure of is the process of smudging itself.  What's a good algorithm for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is pretty old but I've recently gotten interested in this very subject so maybe this might be helpful to someone. I implemented a 'smudge' brush using Imagick for PHP which is roughly based on the smudging technique described in this [paper](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~uffe/xjobb/BrushPaintingAlgorithms.pdf). If you want to inspect the code feel free to have a look at the project: [Magickpaint](http://github.com/fanfare/magickpaint)

Answer (score 2):

Try PythonMagick (ImageMagick library bindings for Python). If you can't find it on your distribution's repositories, get it here: http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/

It has more effect functions than you can shake a stick at.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to apply a [Gaussian blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) (or some other type of blur) to each point in the region defined by your control points.

Comment: That's half of what I'm trying to do.  I guess I should have been more specific.  I'm trying to "push" an area of an image around, similar to the smudge tool in the GIMP or Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to create a grid that your control points moves and then use texture mapping techniques to map the image back onto the distorted grid.

Answer (score 0):

I can vouch for a Gaussian Blur mentioned above, it is quite simple to implement and provides a fairly decent blur result.

James